# Почему не распознаются буквы ввода?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Этот код должен перевести буквы алфавита в определенные цифры, ео почему-то не распознаёт буквы. Где я сделал ошибку?

```
d=(input('lol'))
s=len(d)
a=list(d)
print(a,s)
z=[]
for i in range(s):
    if a=='а':
        z=[0,1]
        print(a[i])
    if a==' ':
        z=[0,0]
    if a=='б':
        z=[1,1]
    if a=='в':
        z=[1,0]
    ...
    else:
        print('неизвестный символ')

print(z)
```

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Tpqu.jpg]

Comment: Фотография монитора - новый уровень скрина :)

Comment: Список никогда не будет равен строке, условие `a=='a'` будет ложным всегда

Comment: @andreymal как мне это исправить?)

Comment: @AlexNagorny не могу знать, я понятия не имею, зачем вы попытались сравнить список со строкой и какой результат вы вообще ожидаете

Answer (score 0):

Как здесь уже было отмечено, a у вас - это список. Сравнивать его таким образом со строковой переменной бессмысленно. 
У вас должно быть что-то типа такого:

```
d = 'абв'
z = []
for letter in d:
    if letter =='а':
        z=[0,1]
        print(letter)
    elif letter ==' ':
        z=[0,0]
        print(letter)
    elif letter =='б':
        z=[1,1]
        print(letter)
    else:
        print('неизвестный символ')
    print(z)
```

что на выходе даст:

```
а
[0, 1]
б
[1, 1]
неизвестный символ
[1, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = input()

symbol_table = {
    ' ': [0, 0],
    'а': [0, 1],
    'б': [1, 1],
    'в': [1, 0]
}

result = []

for symbol in data:
    number = symbol_table.get(symbol)

    if number is not None:
        result.append(number)
    else:
        print('Неизвестный символ %s' % symbol)

print(result)
```